# Disable persistent does not work in redis enterprise cluster on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-operator

I try to creating [redis enterprise cluster](https://developer.redis.com/create/kubernetes/kubernetes-gke) with redis operator.

For declaration of my cluster I write something like below

```
apiVersion: "app.redislabs.com/v1"
kind: "RedisEnterpriseCluster"
metadata:
  name: "harbor-cluster"
spec:
  nodes: 3
  persistentSpec:
    enabled: false
  redisEnterpriseNodeResources:
    limits:
      cpu: 1000m
      memory: 1Gi
    requests:
      cpu: 1000m
      memory: 1Gi
```

But my problem is even I set presistentSpec to false, I see `kubectl describe pvc redis-enterprise-storage-harbor-cluster-0`  show redis try to claim pv and my bootstrapping of my pods is failed.

```
Name:          redis-enterprise-storage-harbor-cluster-0
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        app=redis-enterprise
               redis.io/cluster=harbor-cluster
               redis.io/role=node
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       harbor-cluster-0
Events:
  Type    Reason         Age                      From                         Message
  ----    ------         ----                     ----                         -------
  Normal  FailedBinding  108s (x1321 over 5h31m)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

If I run `kubectl get pods` you can see `harbor-cluster-0` does not ready (because bootstrapping of redis pod is failed)

```
NAME                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
harbor-cluster-0                                  1/2     Running   0          72s
harbor-cluster-services-rigger-557b6f75c8-hgfzj   1/1     Running   0          73s
redis-enterprise-operator-7f8d8548c5-qvd48        2/2     Running   0          6h16m
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: I can see the issue in GitHub created by you: https://github.com/RedisLabs/redis-enterprise-k8s-docs/issues/212. Have you checked the last comment from Lauren? `Is it possible that you had previously created a Redis Enterprise Cluster with the same name before? I am thinking the PVC could be from a previous run.
Can you check if the PVC is older than the REC by comparing their creation timestamp?`

Comment: Yes, thanks to Lauren, my problem is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting comment as the community wiki answer for better visibility

---

Is it possible that you had previously created a Redis Enterprise Cluster with the same name before? I am thinking the PVC could be from a previous run. Can you check if the PVC is older than the REC by comparing their creation timestamp?